# CSS opt-outs on IDs

Tags: css, windows

A hopefully quick css question for you.

Throughout the bulk of my site I have added images in with text and given them a 10px padding along the top to make it look better, like this:

```
#zzmainContent img {padding-top: 10px;}
```

Now I want to add the vary occasional image, within the same < DIV>, but I don't want the padding to take effect. I've created a new ID:

```
#icon {padding-top: -10px; vertical-align: middle;}
```

But it still wants to add the padding as it is still an < img>. How can I 'opt-out' my icon id?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: There's no such thing a negative padding...did you try a zero value.

Comment: @Paulie_D - nice catch! You're right of course and that works correctly.
Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have multiple icons within `#zzmainContent` you should use a class instead of an id.

If your `#icon` rule comes after the `img` rules, add `!important` and see if that helps.

Id-based rule:

```
#icon {padding-top: -10px !important; vertical-align: middle !important;}
```

Class-based rule:

```
.icon {padding-top: -10px !important; vertical-align: middle !important;}
```

These rules both assume that the id or class is an attribute on the image itself.

Comment: Thanks @Sam for the reply. Sadly it didn't work. I changed to a class (so it became .icon) and added !important, but to no avail...

Comment: Can you add the some minimal HTML showing an example of your markup?

Comment: Also, to clarify, my example assumed you left it as an id. If you used a class, as advised, the style rule changes. Answer updated to reflect.